# Writing image to file in python from website

Tags: python, web.py

I wrote this code:

```
class uploadfromfile:
    def POST(self, name=None):
            filename = ''.join(random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') for i in range(20))
            x = web.input(upfile={})
            f = open(filename, 'w')
            f.write(x['upfile'].value)
            f.close()
            imgFromFile(filename)
            return "some html"
```

But it doesn't work. I get a huge error that ends with this: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 15: invalid start byte

The error appears to arrive at f.write(x['upfile'].value), and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Any ideas what is going wrong? I know that the value is in that variable, because if I just return it the image displays in my browser.

Comment: If it's an image, you should probably open the file with 'wb' for binary as the first step.

Comment: @TheSentinel: Since this is very likely to be the OP's actual problem, you should post that as an answer (with an explanation as to why).

Comment: @user1624005: The other possibility here is that you aren't doing the upload form properly, so you're getting a `value` that thinks it's Unicode text instead of binary data. It would help to diagnose your problem if you posted the `form` attributes (we don't need child nodes, just the attributes), and told us: Python 2 or 3? Which `web.py` version? Windows or Unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I can see wrong with the code is that the file isn't opened in binary mode.  When reading at writing files that aren't simple strings, binary mode is required to treat the data as nothing more than bytes.  Simply switch the file opening like to `f = open(filename, 'wb')`to resolve that issue.